# Doctrine2 (Doctrine 2.1) eager loading in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

Let's say I have two entities in my Symfony2 project : `Category` and `Article` (a category having many articles).

In my `CategoryRepository`, I have this method:

```
findAllDummy(){
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
              ->leftJoin('c.Articles a')
              ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

If I remember well, in Symfony1.4 (and the corresponding version of Doctrine), the returned objects would have their 'articles' attribute filled by the corresponding `Article` objects.
Now, in Symfony2, Proxy objects are returned.

So if I loop through a specific category's articles, As many queries as iterations will be executed.

```
foreach($category->getArticles() as $article){
  echo $article->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('')getTitle();
}
```

I understand this is Doctrine2.1's default lazy loading behavior.

**Question 1:** how is this a better solution?
N queries instead of 1.

I tried to force eager loading by doing the following:

```
findAllDummy(){
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
              ->leftJoin('c.articles a')
              ->getQuery()
              ->setFetchMode('Category', 'articles', 'EAGER')
              ->getResult();
}
```

But the result remains the same.

**Question 2:** how to force eager loading in Doctrine2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're joining a table but you're not selecting anything from it. Add `->addSelect('a')` to your query builder. Consider two following SQL queries to understand the difference:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM article a 
JOIN category c ON a.category_id = c.id 
WHERE a.id = 123;

SELECT a.id, a.title, c.id, c.name 
FROM article a 
JOIN category c ON a.category_id = c.id 
WHERE a.id = 123;
```

---

Eager/lazy joining has nothing to do with DQL queries. It defines what should be loaded when you use `$articleRepository->find(123)`.

Comment: @Crozin I'm still a little confused...when you say "it defines what should be loaded", are you referring to what is hydrated?

Comment: @SamSelikoff Yes, if you define `fetch=EAGER` on articles' relation, all articles will be loaded (and hydrated) when you call `categoryRepository->findOne(321)`

Comment: What's the difference between loading and hydrating?

Comment: @SamSelikoff There is non in this context. Treat these two words as synonyms.

Comment: Hmm. So either of the two queries in your answer could be eagerly or lazily loaded?

Comment: @SamSelikoff Yes, you can decide whether you want to load something eagerly or lazily in both, DQL and the `EntityManager::find*()`. You just need to use different "tools": `->addSelect(...)` in DQL and `fetch="EAGER"` in `em->find()`.

Comment: @Crozin It should be `fetch="EAGER"` (with quotes).

Comment: If we have `join` and `select`, we don't need `setFetchMode()`

Comment: you saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

In the part where you try to *"force eager loading"* the problem might be that you use the `fetchMode` method with the wrong variable type for the `$fetchMode` argument. You pass a string `'EAGER'` but the method doesn't expect a string but an integer.

The method expects constants from the `ClassMetadata` class:

```
/**
 * Specifies that an association is to be fetched when it is first accessed.
 */
const FETCH_LAZY = 2;

/**
 * Specifies that an association is to be fetched when the owner of the
 * association is fetched.
 */
const FETCH_EAGER = 3;
```

In the Doctrine documentation chapter **14.7.6.6. Temporarily change fetch mode in DQL** you can see an example on how to use this:

```
$query->setFetchMode("MyProject\User", "address", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
```

So pass either a reference to the constant or an integer that corresponds to the mode you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql), eager loading in this case won't make any difference because you have one-to-many relationship between Category and Article.

> For one-to-many relations, changing the fetch mode to eager will cause to execute one query for every root entity loaded. This gives no improvement over the lazy fetch mode which will also initialize the associations on a one-by-one basis once they are accessed.

So contrary to what @Crozin has said, you can still do eager loading in DQL. 
If you have a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship, eager loading will solve the problem of making extra queries. However to solve your problem in this case you should use `->addSelect('a')` as @Crozin mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

It is a better solution because joins are a much more expensive process than a simple query. While it may seem inefficient, it isn't much of a waste, and quickly becomes more efficient when you aren't loading every bit of every related object.

Comment: This information neither was ever nor wasn't never true.